# Alguém sabe como colocar o "UTF-8" e o "ScrollView" no Android via código Java?

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário dinâmico, então estou fazendo tudo via código java sem usar xml. Alguém sabe como adicionar o UTF-8 e o ScrollView não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os métodos nativos no Android Studio para inserir os códigos em HTML dentro dos métodos disponíveis.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html?